# Group by rows which are in sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

Consider I have a table like this

```
PASSENGER  CITY      DATE
43         NEW YORK  1-Jan-21
44         CHICAGO   4-Jan-21
43         NEW YORK  2-Jan-21
43         NEW YORK  3-Jan-21
44         ROME      5-Jan-21
43         LONDON    4-Jan-21
44         CHICAGO   6-Jan-21
44         CHICAGO   7-Jan-21
```

How would I group Passenger and City column in sequence to get a result like below?

```
PASSENGER  CITY      COUNT
43         NEW YORK  3
44         CHICAGO   1
44         ROME      1
43         LONDON    1
44         CHICAGO   2
```

Comment: How is the *order* of your sequence defined? There is no *as shown order* in a relational table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to deal with such a gaps-and-islands problem is to calculate a ranking for the gaps.

Then group also on that ranking.

```
SELECT PASSENGER, CITY
, COUNT(*) AS "Count" 
-- , MIN("DATE") AS StartDate
-- , MAX("DATE") AS EndDate
FROM (
  SELECT q1.*
  , SUM(gap) OVER (PARTITION BY PASSENGER ORDER BY "DATE") as Rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT PASSENGER, CITY, "DATE"
    , CASE
      WHEN 1 = TRUNC("DATE")
             - TRUNC(LAG("DATE") 
                     OVER (PARTITION BY PASSENGER, CITY ORDER BY "DATE")) 
      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as gap
    FROM table_name t
  ) q1
) q2
GROUP BY PASSENGER, CITY, Rnk
ORDER BY MIN("DATE"), PASSENGER
```

| PASSENGER | CITY | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | NEW YORK | 3 |
| 43 | LONDON | 1 |
| 44 | CHICAGO | 1 |
| 44 | ROME | 1 |
| 44 | CHICAGO | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85af947f5bbd187aedbf5f3f94b3624f)*

Comment: Hi Luk, how would your approach change if I had timestamps instead of dates?

Comment: Have you tried with timestamps? You see, the query is already truncating to '00:00:00' to flag the gaps.  So it might not matter as long it's still about 1 different day.

Comment: Yeah, what about grain is not 1 different day and I need sequence of within day as well?

Comment: Or you could try to change the calculation for gap yourself. F. e. check if the [timestamp difference](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle/) isn't bigger than 24 hours.

Comment: I'll ask another question

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY passenger
  ORDER     BY "DATE"
  MEASURES
    FIRST(city) AS city,
    COUNT(*)    AS count
  PATTERN (same_city+)
  DEFINE
    same_city AS FIRST(city) = city
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (PASSENGER, CITY, "DATE") AS
SELECT 43, 'NEW YORK',  DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, 'CHICAGO',   DATE '2021-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 'NEW YORK',  DATE '2021-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 'NEW YORK',  DATE '2021-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, 'ROME',      DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 'LONDON',    DATE '2021-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, 'CHICAGO',   DATE '2021-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, 'CHICAGO',   DATE '2021-01-07' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | PASSENGER | CITY | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 43 | NEW YORK | 3 |
> | 43 | LONDON | 1 |
> | 44 | CHICAGO | 1 |
> | 44 | ROME | 1 |
> | 44 | CHICAGO | 2 |

---

If you have ordered the input result set (note: tables should be considered to be unordered) and want to maintain the order then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT t.*, ROWNUM AS rn FROM table_name t)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY passenger
  ORDER     BY RN
  MEASURES
    FIRST(rn)     AS rn,
    FIRST("DATE") AS "DATE",
    FIRST(city)   AS city,
    COUNT(*)      AS count
  PATTERN (same_city+)
  DEFINE
    same_city AS FIRST(city) = city
)
ORDER BY rn
```

Outputs:

> | PASSENGER | RN | DATE | CITY | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 43 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | NEW YORK | 3 |
> | 44 | 2 | 04-JAN-21 | CHICAGO | 1 |
> | 44 | 5 | 05-JAN-21 | ROME | 1 |
> | 43 | 6 | 04-JAN-21 | LONDON | 1 |
> | 44 | 7 | 06-JAN-21 | CHICAGO | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18c95d082a4c6f7ded09a7bb4f03200a)*